# Unexplained cached public fingerprint for private ssh key with ssh-keygen

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, private-key

I'm having a weird problem with SSH.

I'm using `ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa` to generate the public fingerprint from my private ssh key `id_rsa`.

However, no matter how I replace or change the contents of my private ssh key file `id_rsa`, the `ssh-keygen -l` command gives the same results.

It's like the key or fingerprint are being cached somehow.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer while writing the question.

If you do not have a public key file which corresponds to your private key (`id_rsa.pub` in this example), then `ssh-keygen -l` will calculate the public key from your private key, and use this calculated public key to calculate the public fingerprint, as expected.

However, if you DO have a public key file (e.g. `id_rsa.pub`), then `ssh-keygen -l` will not bother to calculate the public key, and will instead use the public key file to get the fingerprint.

This is weird behavior, since all the data you could need is in the private key, and it doesn't take long to calculate the public key from the private one.  It also doesn't check if the private and public keys actually match.  However, this odd behavior is actually documented in the man page for `ssh-keygen`.  So, basically, yes, there is a cache: the cache is the public key file (e.g. `id_rsa.pub`).

You can safely delete the public key file and regenerate it with `ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: The .pub file has a purpose: The private key formats used by OpenSSH are _fully_ encrypted, so ssh tools would need to ask you for your passphrase even if it was just to retrieve "public" data. For people who have multiple keys, this could result in a lot of unnecessary passphrase prompts during authentication.